# Uninstalled rbenv but path is still set to rbenv

Tags: ruby, rbenv

I uninstalled rbenv using

```
brew uninstall rbenv
```

My system still seeks rbenv though, rather than os x native version.

```
$ ruby -v

-bash: /Users/daan/.rbenv/shims/ruby: No such file or directory
```

Where do I change the path back to local version?

Comment: Have you restarted shell?

Comment: did the trick thanks